# Possibility of writing to a wrong object with callback

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using a NodeJS Socket.IO server for handling realtime things. There is also an event in Socket.IO for authenticating a user. The code looks as follows:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080)

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('auth', function(id) {

        conn.query('SELECT id FROM u WHERE id = ?', id, function(e, result) {

            socket.id = result[0].id
        })
    })
)}
```

My worries are about this line here:

```
socket.id = result[0].id
```

This is in a callback. When the DB executed the query.
So my question is: Is there a possibility that there can be wrong assignment with a lot of of connections at the same time? Seems that this happened already and data got assigned to the wrong socket object. Are there better methods for reliably do things like this?

Comment: No, a socket calling an event shouldn't get information from another socket's call to the same event. It's all async. Your problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: But it happened. And in the code is no other possibility for "changing" things like this. But I will keep monitoring it, if it will happen again.

Answer (score 0):

The Socket object has a built-in field `id`. From http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#

> strong textSocket#id:String
>
> A unique identifier for the socket session, that comes from the
>   underlying Client.

Your code is trying to assign a different value to this built-in field, which seems like a bad idea.  You should try to rename "your" `id` field to something else like `authId` or `userId` to avoid this conflict.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but this isn't causing the issue.